# Cheap german bikes and online shopping

Tags: germany

What you guys think about bike-discount.de
Has anyone had experience with this website and Radon bikes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've ordered small and large parts from bike-discount.de. 100% satisfied and cheapest price for those specific parts at that time after comparing with at least 6 other known e-shops.

Regarding cheap german bikes, I don't know about Radon (they don't seem to be well known to the rest of the EU), but I own a canyon torque for the last 3 years and a pal of mine owns a yt noton (both companies well known around the globe). Both are cheap german bikes with high end specs at lowest price possible. We are both 100% satisfied with the bikes, the build and 90% satisfied with after market support.

Answer (score 1):

I have ordered components there several times and in most cases everything went fine. The last order had some flaws but as far as I could reconstruct that was more the parcel service's fault than theirs.

I cannot tell anything about their bikes from own experience but the last time I was buying a bike (some 6 or so years ago) a lo of people seemed to recommend their Radon MTBs as being good bikes with quite good components. It looked as if one would get a lot of value for the money.